# MATLAB: My for loop is not retaining data in my scatterplot for each iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, scatter-plot

All of my code works, but for some reason as it iterates, it will not store the data found in each trial. I've stepped through it multiple times and i can see it slowly adding the data for each trial one by one but the final scatterplot only has the last trial. I know it has something to do with storing the data or where my scatterplot is but I am not super good with malab.

```
    for trial = 1:50
        trial_start = (trial-1) * trial_duration;
        window_start = trial_start - time_before_trial_start;
        window_end = trial_start + trial_duration + time_after_trial_end;

        % times for current trial
        trial_event_times = event_times(event_times >= window_start & event_times <= window_end);

        trial_numbers = trial * ones(size(trial_event_times));
        

        % raster plot for current trial
        scatter(trial_event_times, trial);
        
        % x and y axis
        xlim([-0.5, 1.5]);
        ylim([0, 50]);
        xlabel('Time (s)');
        ylabel('Trial');
        title(['Raster Plot for (' signal_title ')']);
        

    end
```

Comment: Try giving `hold on` before your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Keep hold on within the current figure before each of your scatter plot, and then hold the axes off after for-loop.

```
    for trial = 1:50
      trial_start = (trial-1) * trial_duration;
      window_start = trial_start - time_before_trial_start;
      window_end = trial_start + trial_duration + time_after_trial_end;

      % times for current trial
      trial_event_times = event_times(event_times >= ...
        window_start &   event_times <= window_end);

      trial_numbers = trial * ones(size(trial_event_times));
    
      % raster plot for current trial
      hold on
      scatter(trial_event_times, trial);
    
      % x and y axis
      xlim([-0.5, 1.5]);
      ylim([0, 50]);
      xlabel('Time (s)');
      ylabel('Trial');
      title(['Raster Plot for (' signal_title ')']);
    
    end

    hold off % don't forget
```